# How will deleting a managed instance affect remaining managed instances within an Azure vnet/subnet?

Tags: azure, instance, managed

I have 3 managed instances within a vnet/subnet. I want to delete one of them. How will that affect the remaining managed instances? Having trouble finding docs that address this.

Comment: How do you plan to delete the managed instance?

Comment: Will delete using the Delete button on the portal page for that MI. Never having done it before, I need to know that it will not affect the other MI's on the VirtualCluster, or change the NSG in any way...

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the managed instance group to two instances instead of three? Then do that. Deleting an instance that is managed will be treated as a failure, which will launch a new instance.

Comment: I did not specifically set up a group. I created 2 extra managed instances in a VNET with same subnet.

Comment: I am not sure what you have configured now. Do you mean you created managed instance groups with one instance? Then just delete the managed instance group.

Comment: I created the first managed instance. I then created a second managed instance using the same vnet/subnet. Then I created a third managed instance using the same vnet/subnet. They share a common NSG. I did not specifically create a group.